# Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 linux whien generating signed apk

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu, apk, signed-apk

```
Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

In Android Studio 3.4 using Ubuntu 16.04 when i generating Signed APK this error is coming .
But when i am generating debug apk it is ok.
I have tried many solutions from SO itself,i haven't find any solution yet.
Any one please know about this ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added these lines to project build.gradle file  and i am able to make a generated signed apk .

```
allprojects {
     configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
        }
    }
}
```